# IdentityServer4 Pass Data to ProfileService

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have an identity server 4 implementation that allows clients to switch between sites via a website.
Each user has a lot of site-specific information I wish to return as claims - using reference tokens and introspection.
I have implemented a profile service that returns all information by site but this is potentially a lot of information as some users have access to a lot of sites.

At the moment I am generating a list of claims on login that contains a list of sites that the user has access to. The client sets a header on each request which defines the site they wish to fetch the data from.. This works well for the api as each site is normally a different database and we only want to deploy a single API. From a claims perspective, I'm struggling.

Each client implements AddAuthentication().AddOAuth2Introspection() in startup to configure introspection but I can't see how I can customize the call so the site is added to the request and available to IProfileService in the identity server.

I can't include the site at login because users can switch between sites at will via the UI - or via API calls so somehow I need to be able to pass extra data to the ProfileService and customize the claims there.

It's worth mentioning that for simplicity I have only mentioned sites. There is actually other information I need to pass to get the required claims data - I've just kept it out of this question to hopefully help.
Does anybody have a clue how I could do this?